# Real-time sequence classification with Markov Chains vs HMM vs CRF

Tags: machine-learning, classification, conditional-probability, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I see that Markov Chains are useful for providing the conditional probabilities for each individual symbol of the test sequence. So this really gives an incremental overview on how the sequence is evolving, by seeing the conditional probability distributions for each time step, as opposed to just classifying the entire test sequence. Thus, they are useful for real-time classifications, however, a lot of real life applications require a more hidden state architecture.

I'm a bit confused on how HMM and CRF work with this respect. They are both sequence classifiers, but if I want to incrementally observe the sequence, is it correct to then incorporate a sliding window to obtain subsequences and then run each window through the HMM or CRF to obtain a conditional probability distribution for that specific window?